# Add both a title above and a note below a figure when knitting Rmarkdown to HTML

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I am knitting an Rmarkdown document to HTML with `bookdown::html_document2`. How can I include both a title above the figure and a note below the figure?

For example, this code lets me produce a figure with a title above the figure. But how can I also include a note below the figure?

To be clear, *I do not* want to include the note below the ggplot with `+ labs(caption = "Text")`, I want to have the note in the same HTML style as the figure title above the figure.

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.topcaption = TRUE) # Display figure title above the figure
```

Figure \@ref(fig:figure) shows some results.

```{r figure, fig.cap="Figure Title (which I want above the figure)"}
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg) +
  geom_point()
```
````

Comment: Why doesn't `... + labs(title="My title", caption="My caption")` do what you want?

Comment: Because I need the note to be **separate** from the figure, as is common in scientific publications. This is really easy in LaTeX. I need the same when knitting to HTML.

Comment: OK.  That's a useful clarification.

Comment: You could use the figure LaTeX code in your HTML file.

Comment: I doubt that this would work, but happy to be convinced otherwise if you can show me how to do it with a reproducible example.